# Looping through nested list in array react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, where one object is a list of varying length (varies by object). I've tried doing a nested map function but that isn't working, for the nested function (see example below), I'm getting the error 'user.people.map is not a function'.

I've included some sample code and data below to explain.

**data file**

```
export default [
{
  id: uuid(),
  name: 'Random',
  people: ['x','y','z']
},
{
  id: uuid(),
  name: 'Modnar',
  people: ['a','b']
}
]
```

**Code**

```
  import data from './data'
  const users = useState(data);

  {users.map(u => {
      {u.people.map(x => {
        return "hey"
      })}
  })}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you import data in your code file

Comment: The fact that `user.people.map` is throwing an error but not `users.map`, suggests that the import is correct but you are assigning a value to the people property which is not an array. Do you make changes to the data array anywhere in your code?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus It's just an import statement. I don't make any changes other than what's there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bouman-t8ksy

```
Hope this helps!

import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        {
          id: "uuid",
          name: "Random",
          people: ["x", "y", "z"]
        },
        {
          id: "uuid",
          name: "Modnar",
          people: ["a", "b"]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map(u => {
          let str = u.people.map(x => {
            return "This is people";
          });
          return (
            <h1>
              {u.name} {str}
            </h1>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a const Function name = Props => {} arrow function which this doesn't work in, should I change my component? It's a stateless function up until here.

Comment: Most Welcome...you can use the same const function and embed the return logic alone. This should do ✌️

Comment: Thanks again but I keep running into the same errors when I embed the logic. Are you able to point me towards converting it into an arrow function?

Comment: PS I updated my code with what I've implemented thus far with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your first line of code `const users = useState(data)`. If you replace it with the following `const [users, setUsers] = useState(data)` it will work.

It's destructuring the users object from the array that [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) is returning. The second value is the setter for the state.

You can find a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-tree-4dum8).

Answer (score -1):

Combine the two arrays into one and do plumbing?

```
const data = []
const descStr = `<h1>Should print as many times as there are entries in 
the list</h1>`
users.forEach(user => {
  data.push({...user, desc: descStr.repeat(users.length)})
})

{data.map((user) =>
return(<div>
  <h1>{user.name}</h1>
 {user.desc}

</div>)
```

Comment: This is not helpful, the return is unnecessary.

Comment: Edited my answer